# Return value of a mocked function does not have `then` property

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, testing, redux, jestjs

I have the following async call in one of my React components:

```
onSubmit = (data) => {
    this.props.startAddPost(data)
        .then(() => {
            this.props.history.push('/');
        });
};
```

The goal here is to redirect the user to the index page only once the post has been persisted in Redux (`startAddPost` is an async action generator that sends the data to an external API using axios and dispatches another action that will save the new post in Redux store; the whole thing is returned, so that I can chain a `then` call to it in the component itself). It works in the app just fine, but I'm having trouble testing it.

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';

import { AddPost } from '../../components/AddPost';
import posts from '../fixtures/posts';

let startAddPost, history, wrapper;

beforeEach(() => {
    startAddPost = jest.fn();
    history      = { push: jest.fn() };
    wrapper      = shallow(<AddPost startAddPost={startAddPost} history={history} />);
});

test('handles the onSubmit call correctly', () => {
    wrapper.find('PostForm').prop('onSubmit')(posts[0]);

    expect(startAddPost).toHaveBeenLastCalledWith(posts[0]);
    expect(history.push).toHaveBeenLastCalledWith('/');
});
```

So I obviously need this test to pass, but it fails with the following output:

```
● handles the onSubmit call correctly

TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

at AddPost._this.onSubmit (src/components/AddPost.js:9:37)
at Object.<anonymous> (src/tests/components/AddPost.test.js:25:46)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7)
```

So how can I fix this? I suspect this is a problem with the test itself because everything works well in the actual app. Thank you!

Comment: It seems that `startAddPost` is a mock function. Why do you expect it to return a promise?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not testable in the first place. You pass in a callback to the action and execute it after saving the data to the database like so,

```
export function createPost(values, callback) {
  const request = axios.post('http://localhost:8080/api/posts', values)
    .then(() => callback());

  return {
    type: CREATE_POST,
    payload: request
  };
}
```

The callback should be responsible for the above redirection in this case. The client code which uses the action should be like this.

```
  onSubmit(values) {
    this.props.createPost(values, () => {
      this.props.history.push('/');
    });
  }
```

This makes your action much more flexible and reusable too.

Then when you test it, you can pass a stub to the action, and verify whether it is called once. Writing a quality, testable code is an art though.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that the `startAddPost` function is a mock function which **does not** return a *Promise*, but your actual `this.props.startAddPost` function **does** return a *Promise*.

That's why your code works but fails when you try to test it, leading to the `cannot read property....` error.

To fix this make your mocked function return a `Promise` like so -

```
beforeEach(() => {
    startAddPost = jest.fn().mockReturnValueOnce(Promise.resolve())
    ...
});
```

Read more about `mockReturnValueOnce` [here](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/mock-functions.html#mock-return-values).